# How can delete duplicare result of acf fields to loop wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have one custom post type and I have created one select field with acf. I need to remove into loop, egual result of option.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'agentiestero',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 150,
        'orderby'=> 'title', 
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );                                                         
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>                                                            

        <option value="<?php the_field('localita_estero'); ?>"><?php the_field('localita_estero'); ?></option>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to clean up result:

```
    <?php
        $result = array();
         if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            $field = get_field('localita_estero');
            if(in_array($field,$result))
                continue;
            $result[] = $field;
?>                                                            
            <option value="<?php echo $field; ?>"><?php echo $field; ?></option>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @SEOExpert your welcome ,If this solved your issue, please click the 'checkmark' to accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over posts is not the best option here. What you most likely want is to iterate over the choices of your ACF select field. To do this, you have to find out your field's field key (e.g., `field_5bf68deadbeef`) and obtain the field object to get all possible choices from there.

Replace your loop above by the following:

```
$localization_field = get_field_object('field_5bf68deadbeef');                  

foreach ($localization_field['choices'] as $key => $label) {                    
?>                                                                              
    <option value="<?= $key ?>"> <?= $label ?> </option>                        
<?php                                                                           
}
```

This code will obtain the definition of your Select field and iterate over all possible choices. Assuming your choices are value:text pairs, it will insert the value as `<option value="...">` and the text as the label.